# How can I drop several rows from my Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, drop

I have a dataframe (called my_df1) and want to drop several rows based on certain dates. How can I create a new dataframe (my_df2) without the dates '2020-05-01' and '2020-05-04'?

I tried the following which did not work as you can see below:

```
my_df2 = mydf_1[(mydf_1['Date'] != '2020-05-01') | (mydf_1['Date'] != '2020-05-04')] 
my_df2.head()
```

[image]

Comment: `mydf_1.loc[your boolean_stuff]` will do. `mydf_1[...]` accesses columns, `mydf_1.loc[...]` accesses rows. Also, you'll want to connect your boolean queries with an ampersand `&` instead of a pipe `|`. A pipe is equivalent to `or`, and every date will not be the first or fourth of may

Comment: What should I enter into [your boolean_stuff]?  I tried mydf_1.loc['Date'  = '2020-05-01']

Comment: `(mydf_1['Date'] != '2020-05-01') & (mydf_1['Date'] != '2020-05-04')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with negation `~` sign:

```
dates=['2020-05-01', '2020-05-04']
my_df2 = mydf_1[~mydf_1['Date'].isin(dates)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be with your logical operator.
You should be using `and` here instead of `or` since you have to select all the rows which are not `2020-05-01` and `2020-05-04`.

The bitwise operators will not be short circuiting and hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

The short explanation about your mistake *AND* and *OR* was addressed by kanmaytacker.
Following a few additional recommendations:

#### Indexing in pandas:

By label `.loc`
By index `.iloc`

By label also works without `.loc` but it's slower as it's composed of chained operations instead of a single internal operation consisting on nested loops (see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)). Also, with `.loc` you can select on more than one axis at a time.

```py
# example with rows. Same logic for columns or additional axis.
df.loc[(df['a']!=4) & (df['a']!=1),:] # ".loc" is the only addition
>>>
   a  b  c
2  0  4  6
```

Your index is a boolean set. This is true for *numpy* and as a consecuence, *pandas* too.

```py
(df['a']!=4) & (df['a']!=1)
>>>
0    False
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```